# Binary matrix optimization, columns and rows sums differences

Tags: matrices, optimization, absolute-value, matrix-rank

For  $A\in \{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ we define:

$A_{i\bullet} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}$,

$A_{\bullet j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij},$

$f(A)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|A_{i \bullet} - A_{\bullet j}|^{3}.$

How to maximize this expression over all possible $A$ matrices ($n$ is fixed)?

Computer simulations for small $n$ suggests that there exists Argmax matrix of rank one.

All Armgmax $A$ also seems to be symmetric.

How can this hypothesis be verified? Can You suggest any reasonable way of attacking this problem or any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $({\tt1},J)$ denote the all-ones vector and matrix, respectively.

Write the vectors formed from the row/col sums in terms of these. 
$$\eqalign{
c &\doteq A_{i*} = A{\tt1}\\
r &\doteq A_{*j} = {\tt1}^TA \\
B_{ij} &\doteq |c_i-r_j| = \big|c_i{\tt1}_j-{\tt1}_ir_j\big| \\
B &\doteq \big|A{\tt11}^T-{\tt11}^TA\big| = \big|AJ-JA\big| \\
G &\doteq AJ-JA \\
}$$
An element-wise sign function yields further relationships.
$$\eqalign{
S &\doteq {\rm sign}(G) &\implies B=S\odot G,\;G=S\odot B \\
B^{\odot 2} &\doteq B\odot B \\
 &= G\odot G \;&\implies  G\odot dG = B\odot dB \\
X &= B\odot G \\
  &= S\odot G^{\odot 2} \;&\implies  S = {\rm sign}(X) \\
}$$
The objective function is the sum of the cube of the (non-negative) elements of $B$. 
$$\eqalign{
f &\doteq J:(B\odot B\odot B) \\
df &= J:3(B\odot B\odot dB) \\
 &= 3(B\odot G):dG \\
 &= 3X:(dA\,J-J\,dA) \\
 &= 3(XJ - JX):dA \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}
 &= 3(XJ - JX) \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields
$$\eqalign{
XJ - JX &= 0 \\
}$$
which is a Sylvester equation for $X$.

After solving for $X$, one can calculate $S = {\rm sign}(X)$

And then take the element-wise root to obtain $G=(S\odot X)^{\odot 1/2}$

The definition of $G$ yields another Sylvester equation to be solved for $A$ in terms of $(G,J)$.

The symbol $(\odot)$ denotes the element-wise product and $(:)$ denotes the trace product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)\\$$
**NB:** There will be multiple solutions to the first Sylvester equation, corresponding to local minima and maxima of the objective function.

In particular, the trivial solution $X=0$ yields
$\big(G=0,\,A=\alpha I+\beta J+\gamma K,\,f=0\big)\,$

where $(I,K)$ are the identity and counter-identity, respectively.

This solution is the global minimum and should not be selected.

In fact, the objective function can be written in terms of $X$
$$f = J:\big|X\big|^{\odot 3/2}$$
So whichever Sylvester solution maximizes this value is the that should be selected.

More solutions occur at $\,X=\alpha I+\beta J+\gamma K$

Comment: Thank You sincerely for this great answer!

Comment: Looking at it again, I realized that I did not incorporate the $A_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ constraint. So the constrained solution will more difficult than this.

Comment: Taking the constraint into account, it appears that
$$A=e_j{\tt1}^T+{\tt1}e_k^T-e_je_k^T$$
maximizes the objective, where $\{e_i\}$ denotes the standard basis vectors.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a solution. Note that, if $A$ is Argmax then $\tilde{A}=(1^{n\times n} - A)$ is also - it satisfies $f(A)=f(\tilde{A})$. Then rank of $\tilde{A}$ is 1. Is this an educated guess or have you some reasoning under this answer?

Comment: The constrained solution is an educated guess, I cannot find an analytical solution. Extending your reflected solution a bit: $\;f(A)=f(A^r)$ is satisfied by $$A^r = \pm(\alpha I+\beta J+\gamma K-A)$$

Comment: I will edit my question, because it can be actually proven that constrains are crucial - there must exist Argamx $A\in \{0,1\}$. It can be seen by basic differentiation.